# if-up.d script not working?

Tags: boot, networking, iptables

I'm trying to make NAT routing persistent on my Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance (for OpenVPN; currently I need to run it every time after boot):

```
ubuntu@vpn:~$ cat /etc/network/if-up.d/vpn-routing
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it's not working:

```
ubuntu@vpn:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas why?  Does it matter that I have `ufw` enabled?  I didn't see anything interesting/relevant in syslog (though I wasn't sure what to look for).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: not working for me either.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the file doesn't have a shebang line. It should be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Also make sure the file has execution permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/vpn-routing
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Actually the #!/bin/sh fixed it for me.  Though there could be any number of reasons it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with this myself.
One handy way of debugging is to enable the logfile for ppp...
sudo touch /var/log/ppp-ipupdown.log

then when I bring up a ppp session I can see how my script is behaving.

Comment: There's no output in Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Merely creating that file, of course does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Apologies - my response (all those years ago) wasn't very clear :-) I should have added that it was useful for me specifically debugging ppp where the default ppp scripts such as /etc/ppp/ip-up and /etc/ip-down already supported logging based on the existence of the file.